# How to go about internationalization?

Tags: javascript, python, internationalization, flask, jinja2

I'm building a web application that will be in a single language (Dutch) at launch. However, at some point it might be translated to other languages as well, which is why I want to have internationalization build in from the start.

The problem is that currently there are 3 separate places that display strings, namely the templates, the python backend and some javascript. Since I've never internationalized an application of any kind I was wondering if there is some way of avoiding this spread? And also, what is the *best* way to go about internationalization?

Edit: As a bit of clarification, I'm using the following parts: Jinja2, Flask, WTForms jQuery, and on top of that a bunch of Python and Javascript code.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) is the most widely used tool for i18n. However, every language and framework implements it's own wrappers around this:

- python: [gettext module](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html)
- flask, jinja2, WTForms: [flask-babel extension](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Babel/)
- javascript, jquery: <del>[gettext plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/gettext)</del>

All of them should use the same translation files, so they should be able work together without any duplication in the translations.

Comment: That's great! The only thing I'm missing is how to translate large bodies of text inside templates.

Comment: Babel has a [jinja extension](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#jinja-extensions). 

There are two ways to mark text in templates for extraction into your catalog:

    {{ _('translate me!') }}

and 

    {% trans %}translate longer text block.{% endtrans %}

Comment: the jquery plugin link is dead

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thanks for your feedback. You're right, I've seen there are a few alternatives like [jquery-i18n](https://github.com/bryanwb/jquery-i18n) and [jquery-i18n.js](https://github.com/yckart/jquery.i18n.js), but not being sure about how good they are, I prefer to strike through the broken link and let people investigate what works for them.